# Monodevelop fails to build, can't find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll'

Tags: monodevelop

I am trying to build a web api project using monodevelop on a mac. The thing is that after a few hiccups (explained in a question that turned out to be so messy I have just deleted) I get to the point of getting this error

```
/Users/myuser/git/LiveData/LiveData/CSC: Error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Windows PDB writer is not available -- could not find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll' (CS0041) (LiveData)
```

In a windows machine the same project builds using visual studio targeting mono 4.5.

When I click on the error it tells me that /Users/myuser/git/LiveData/LiveData/CSC doesn't exist

Another thing is that in the folder structure of the solution there's a package folder (not the one inside the project) and inside this one I have a folder called Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.3.2 that has inside another folder called "tools" that contains among other things csc.exe and the dll thta can't be found.

I have tried to install the dll directly in the project using nuget but even if it was installed the build showed me the same error

Thanks,

Comment: what version of MonoDevelop is this? what's the Microsoft.DiaSymReader assembly?

Comment: Xamarin Studio 5.10. Regarding the dll not sure if I get your question, you mean the version?

Comment: no, I mean what I wrote: what is it, where does that come from? why does the compilation require it?

Comment: Oh, afaik is an implementation for reading and writing pdb files

Comment: MonoDevelop 5.10 doesn't use roslyn but the Mono compiler, so the compilation shouldn't be dealing with Microsoft tools to read pdb files at all, not sure what the hell happened there

Comment: Yeah, well. I will try to spend more time today on this. Thanks

Comment: Any progress/ insight to this?  We are running into same issue.

Comment: @Patrick unfortunately not, gave up eventually until I can have more time for this project. So would really appreciate if you post any update

Answer (score 2):

As for workaround for now you can just limit usage of Microsoft.Net.Compilers to Release configuration (edit *.csproj file):

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release' And Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

take a look at beginning of condition:

```
'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'
```

This way I can build and debug locally and build my project ie. in appharbor.

Answer (score 1):

Building the project in release configuration should fix it!

Comment: should be a comment

Comment: Ok, just joined. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be completely related but may be helpful in some ways. Regarding the issue on 'could not find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll', have a look at this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3016

It seems like the solution is either:

- Dependency to Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms needed for RID graph which 
  was missing. Any package which has transitive dependency on it (like 
  NETStandard.Library) could also make things work.
- Adding dependency     to "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-" or
  "NETStandard.Library":"1.5.0-" make it work.
- adding       Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms works as well