# Could not find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll

Tags: c#, dll, mono, rider

I'm trying to build a project in Rider using Mono and I can keep on getting this error:

> Error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Windows
>   PDB writer is not available -- could not find
>   Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll'

Does anybody have any idea why I'm getting this error? I've tried searching for it online and all I could find was a previous SO question that never got answered: [Monodevelop fails to build, can't find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413584/monodevelop-fails-to-build-cant-find-microsoft-diasymreader-native-x86-dll)
I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, you are looking under the wrong rock.  This is not a Mono error, it comes from CoreCLR.  Jetbrains *announced* that they were planning on supporting it.  How far along that got and *exactly* what version you have is all very unclear.  Use the company's support channels to find assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Right, the library exists. but on Visual Studio, using NuGet [link to nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native) it will add the reference and add the Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.(arch).dll into //debug, once you build it. So, you must find the way to get such .dll.

Once you have the .dll with the arch you need. Proceed to add as a external reference on Monodevelop [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017624/how-to-add-external-references-in-monodevelop) the dll.

Begin to build.