# Error while building C# Console Application: Error CS0041 Cannot find a module

Tags: c#

When I'm trying to build an application I get this error:

> Error CS0041 Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Unable to
>   load DLL 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll': Cannot find a
>   module. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'.

It happens only while building C# console application. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

**EDIT**: Repairing application solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe you need to add this package `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`.

Comment: Possible of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/40648121/4588756

Comment: I've installed Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native via package manager console. But build still doesn't work... Same error over and over again. @Llazar also tried adding Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms package - didn't help.