# Failure writing debug information: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I installed a VS2017, tried to develop a first app in VS2017. 
File > New Project > Visual Basic > Windows Desktop > Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)
simply tried to run an app with only one label on form, but build error comes up, I clicked on "Yes" then dialogue box appears (image).
[image]
Error Code- BC37225
Error Message- `Failure writing debug information: Unable to load DLL <br>'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`
Then searched SO, read and tried solutions, but not worked.
What I tried from SO is- 
[Error while building C# Console Application: Error CS0041 Cannot find a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320619/error-while-building-c-sharp-console-application-error-cs0041-cannot-find-a-mod)
(1) installed Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (nuget package)
(2) installed Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll (nuget package)
(3) [Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953998/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-diasymreader-native-amd64-dll)
in this, solution is available (accepted answer), but I don't know from where to delete these lines of code.

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <Deterministic> true </Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

what could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

When the build errors dialog comes up it asks if you want to run a previous build because the current build will not compile (won't make a new .exe file) Since this is the first run of your program there was no previous build, no .exe. What you need to resolve are the build errors.