# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project which is built under 4.7.1. when I rebuild the solution, getting following error.

> Error CS0041  Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Unable to
>   load DLL 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll': The specified
>   module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
>   project name  Location name\CSC   1   N/A

I have tried to install dll from nuget  ([Could not find Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965620/could-not-find-microsoft-diasymreader-native-x86-dll)). but no luck.

environment:

Windows 7 VisualStudio 2017 community edition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try deleting it

```
<PropertyGroup>
<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When the attribute of Deterministic is set to true, the DLL / EXE files generated by your program compilation will be determined. The HASH values of these files are the same no matter how many times they are regenerated. This is a great feature, but at the same time it can cause compilation errors. You can refer to this blog for more details [blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/04/05/…](http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/04/05/deterministic-builds-in-roslyn.html).

Comment: thank you. I sovle my problem. But does anyone know how to fixed it without remove

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make sure all new projects are created without this property?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (and few more similar errors with dlls). Solved it by installing missing KBs.

KB3118401: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118401/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

KB2533623: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2533623/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remot